# SQL Server Performance Issue - Wait Stats?

Tags: sql-server, performance

My laptop is an HP Studio G3 with 16 GB RAM and a Xeon E3-1505 v5 CPU and a 512 GB NVMe Samsung SSD so it's supposed to be a pretty fast machine.

Just recently, I was asked to look at the performance of an application and I duly copied the database and application onto my laptop (SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition on Windows 10) for testing.

Imagine my surprise when I found that it ran *far* slower on my machine than just about anyone else's. To verify my machine's slow performance, I created a simple query that would insert a large number of rows and, sure enough, running it on my machine vs other far slower machines in the office, mine was the slowest (around 50 seconds) and it gets much worse if the row count is increased.

Here's my (admittedly rough) query:

```
CREATE TABLE [PerfExample]
(
    [ExampleId] [INT] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    [Content] [NTEXT]
)

ALTER TABLE [PerfExample] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_PerfExample] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ExampleId])

DECLARE @id int 
SELECT @id = 1

WHILE @id >= 1 and @id <= 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [PerfExample] 
    VALUES ('Test', 'Test')

    SELECT @id = @id + 1
END

SELECT * FROM [PerfExample]

DELETE FROM [PerfExample]

DROP TABLE [PerfExample]
```

So if I make that loop value less than 1000 or so, it runs really quickly but anything above that and it seems to hit a wall at which point the disk usage hits 100% as though it's run out of memory. I did note that the WRITELOG wait state appears to be high.

I've set the maximum memory to a suitably large value with no effect. The number of threads is set to 512.

Can anyone suggest what the issue might be?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s - looks like invalid logic in the while-loop

Comment: @Joe: sorry - yes, you're right - fixed it

Comment: Do the other machines also have one HD? The data and log files should be on separate disks to improve i/o performance.

Comment: The other machines are all lower spec than mine and quite a bit older though all do have SSD drives. My SSD is equivalent to the Samsung 950 PRO and benchmarks as fast as anything else out there. All of them are using single disks (they're laptops too).

Comment: First off, you're not doing this from Studio while forgetting `SET NOCOUNT ON`, right? SSMS will slow down and eat more resources as its output window fills up. Second, your disk may have problems with latency; every insert is a separate transaction in this script and must be committed before the next one can happen. Wrap the loop in `BEGIN TRANSACTION`..`COMMIT` and see what happens (this should speed things up on any machine, but particularly if write latency is bad). Third, you can use perf counters to check things like disk queue length and pending I/O; howtos are readily available online.